# BSON Encoding and Decoding C#

Tags: c#, encoding, decoding, bson

I used this code to decode bytes sent from the server

```cs
packets = SimpleBSON.Load(ReceivedBytes);
for (int i = 0; i < packets["mc"]; i++)
{
    BSONObject packet = packets["m" + i] as BSONObject;
    //here i can use the received packet
    packet["hey"] = "hello";
}
```

But I am struggling in encoding it back again
I am using [Kernys.BSON](https://github.com/kernys/Kernys.Bson)
I tried this

```cs
var obj = new BSONObject();
obj["m" + 0] = new BSONObject();
obj["m" + 0]["hey"] = "hi";
```

But for some reason this is not working

Comment: Please define ["it's not working"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: I fixed it, i mean it wasnt the same

Comment: Do you mean you fixed your issue? If it is done in a way that may help others, then you are allowed to answer your own question

Comment: oh, never thought of that

Comment: why is my post getting down voted :/
at least the down voter should specify the reason so I wouldn't post bad questions again

Answer (score 1):

this is how I fixed it

```cs
var GPd = new BSONObject();
                GPd["m" + 0] = new BSONObject();
                GPd["m" + 0]["hey"] = "hi";
                GPd["mc"] = 1;
                byte[] mainsend = SimpleBSON.Dump(GPd);
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                using (BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream))
                {
                    byte[] bsonDump = SimpleBSON.Dump(GPd);

                    binaryWriter.Write(bsonDump.Length + 4);
                    binaryWriter.Write(bsonDump);
                }
                //memorystream.ToArray is the encoded bytes
            }
```